# Get position of the "viewport" in mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad, position, mobile-safari, viewport

Is there a way to determine the position of the "viewport" in mobile safari on a web page? Like x, y, w, h pixel positions of what the phone is currently seeing on the page?

Comment: From the Obj-C side or from the JS side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript (on Mobile Safari) you can use window.pageXOffset and window.pageYOffset to get the x and y offsets, window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to get w and h.

Comment: This fails if you reload the page and the page is already scrolled down. Reports "0".

Comment: @typeoneerror: I got a similar problem with the "already scrolling down": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654024/mobilesafari-auto-scroll-pan-to-specific-position-on-page-after-reload
Please let me know if you find any solution for the problem.