# mobileSafari: Auto Scroll/Pan to specific position on page after reload

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, viewport

I'm programming a Webpage/-Application for the iPhone. I need to scroll to a specific position after page reload, no matter where I scrolled to while using the page before. 
The script I use works fine in firefox but not in mobileSafari. In contrast to firefox, mobileSafari seems to save the position I scrolled to previously and jumps there after reload, ignoring my scrollTo triggered on reload.

This is the code I use:

```
function scroller(){scrollTo(1000,1000);}
window.addEventListener("load",scroller, false);
```

It works with click-events that I trigger manually. If I click a button to trigger the scroll function than the scrolling is done.
I tried to trigger the click via a synthetic event javascript, but this does not work either.

Is there any way the scrolling can be archived on reload and/or other not explicitly user triggered events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a solution for the actual problem which seems to be a bug. But I found a workaround. This is not to trigger the scrolling directly via an onload event but to use a setTimeout()

```
init(){
setTimeout(scrollTo(0, 1000), 10)
//more code
}
//more code
window.onload=init;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) prototype !?